# Datetime and RegEx Dates

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, datetime, web-scraping

I'm scraping strings from HTML elements that contain dates. What I'm looking to do is extract the dates with a regular expression and then convert them to a different format using the `datetime` module. The strings follow the following format:

```
Date first available at Amazon.ca: Nov. 23 2017
Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 27 2017
Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 6 2018
```

The tricky thing about this is that only the months with long names are abbreviated.

```
Jan.
Feb.
March
April
May
June
July
Aug.
Sept.
Oct.
Nov.
Dec.
```

My first idea was to select everything but `Date first available at Amazon.ca:`, but clearly this is a bit more difficult to do than I had first imagined.

My next idea was something like `r'^(J|F|M|A|S|O|De)'`, but this obviously won't work since the months aren't located at the beginning of the string.

Now I'm stuck for ideas.

Obviously something like the following regular expression will work, but it seems overly verbose.

`r'(Jan.|Feb.|March|April|May|June|July|Aug.|Sept.|Oct.|Nov.|Dec.)[\d\s]+'`

Comment: Look at module dateutil. It has a date parser that will do what you want without having to fiddle with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the month, day, and year by searching for letters with a possible `"."`:

```
import re, datetime
months = {b:a for a, b in enumerate(['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug.', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.'], 1)}
def convert_date(d:str) -> str:
  month, day, year = d.split()
  return datetime.datetime(int(year), months[month], int(day))

data = ['Date first available at Amazon.ca: Nov. 23 2017', 'Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 27 2017', 'Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 6 2018']
new_data = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\.*\s\d+\s\d+$', i) for i in data]
final_results = [convert_date(i[0]) for i in new_data if i]
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 6, 0, 0)]
```

---

Timings:

```
import time
def timeit(f):
  _t1 = time.time()
  _ = f()
  print(f'{f.__name__}: completed in {time.time()-_t1}')

@timeit
def ajax1234():
  new_data = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\.*\s\d+\s\d+$', i) for i in data]

@timeit
def anthony():
  t = [re.findall('(Jan.|Feb.|March|April|May|June|July|Aug.|Sept.|Oct.|Nov.|Dec.)[\d\s]+', i) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
ajax1234: completed in 4.982948303222656e-05
anthony: completed in 3.314018249511719e-05
```

Comment: trying it right now. your answer on my other thread was completely broken eh?

Comment: it's either outputting empty lists or throwing errors :/

Comment: @Anthony Can you clarify? What input are you testing it on? What are the errors? Is it possible that an input string does not contain a date?

Comment: the exact same inputs i listed above. "list index is out of range", so it must be returning something. all im doing is `first_available = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\.*\s\d+\s\d+$', i)[0] for i in first_available[0].text]` and then `print(first_available)`. the regex works in the browser tester, so something is up with my code

Comment: @Anthony Strange, I am not receiving any errors when I run the code on the input you posted. Copy my example above and test it. Does it raise an error for you?

Comment: its working in a browser tester so the issue seems to be somewhere in my code

Comment: @Anthony It is most likely that there is input data that does not contain a valid date, as described in your post. However, I edited my answer to check the results from `re.findall`, and to remove the possibility of an `IndexError`.

Comment: the only difference may be a space at the very beginning of the string :/ even your new code is still returning empty strings. ill have to figure this out tomo. i gotta head off now :(

Comment: no wonder. because im not working with a list of inputs, but just a string. duhhhh

Comment: is it possible to convert either abbreviated or full names and day and year to say `YY-MM-DD`?

Comment: also, do u think ur regex will be faster than mine?

Comment: @Anthony Please see my recent edit. I also added timings for the regular expressions, and while yours is faster, it does not obtain the correct output.

Comment: hm why do u say my regex doesnt obtain the correct results? ive been using it and havent encountered any issues :/ ty so much for the timings <3 is there not a way to convert the dates using `strptime` from the datetime module?

Comment: @Anthony When I run your regex, I get `[['Nov.'], ['March'], ['March']]`, rather than the full date. Please see my recent edit, as I added the `datetime` implementation

Comment: hmmm its working for me :/ i get the full dates (i.e. `'Dec. 2 1997'`, `'June 24 2001'`, etc), so prolly an issue with your implementation

Comment: ive posted my solution as an answer below if youre interested!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
dlist = [
"Date first available at Amazon.ca: Nov. 23 2017",
"Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 27 2017",
"Date first available at Amazon.ca: March 6 2018"]
print([re.search(r"(?<=\: )[a-zA-Z]+\.*[0-9 ]+" , each).group(0) for each in dlist])
```

Comment: what exactly does `(?<=\: )` do?

Comment: match the string begin wit `: `

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution in full.

```
first_available = ff.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//li[contains(., "Date first available")]')
regex_first_available = re.compile(r'(Jan|Feb|March|April|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\d\s]+')

if len(first_available) > 0:
    first_available = regex_first_available.search(first_available[0].text).group(0)
else:
    first_available = ff.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[text()="Date First Available"]/following-sibling::td[1]').text.replace('.', '')

try:
    first_available = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_available, '%b %d %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    first_available = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_available, '%B %d %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

If somebody improves this approach, I'll select your solution as the answer instead.